# Where is my launcher icon?

Tags: android, amazon-fire-tv

A quiet basic question: I'm developing an app which should also run on the Fire TV. Is there anyway to add a icon to that launcher?

I know I can go the long way over the settings to start my app, but that is not very handy.

I'm also confused how I need to create my icon for that launcher a standard launcher icon is wrong, because Amazon uses differnt icon sizes. I found some confusing informations that the launcher icons come from the amazon store only. Is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are sideloading your apk (`adb install` or pushing from your development environment) then on FireTV you won't see an icon in the launcher for your app, as you rightly point out you will only see it from the Settings | Applications | Manage All Applications menu.

The only way to have an icon appear there is to either submit and publish it, or use [Live App Testing](https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/live-app-testing) if you're not ready to submit and publish publicly but want to invite some beta testers (you can do multiple submissions through Live App Testing before going live)

When you submit your app (either for Live App Testing, or a full submission) there is an option in the developer portal to upload the various assets - icons, screenshots, descriptions, pricing etc

Comment: Great! Thank you for your answer. What are the best practices about creating a seperat Amazon account, can the apps been moved between accounts? Can I share the publisher access between accounts, like in the play store? And finally are there some two token logins possible? Yeah I know much off topic but I couldn't find that informations yet.

Comment: AFAIK sharing accounts means inviting others to become administrator on the one account (across all titles). Moving an app, like on Google Play, isn't straightforward and I don't think there is 2FA - all of these are good questions, but probably best asked via their support https://developer.amazon.com/public/support/contact/contact-us

Answer (score 1):

The default icon for any android app is ic_launcher.png. It's usually located in all the different drawable folder buckets (drawable-mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi). You can change the icon, if you are interested, by placing a new icon in one of the buckets and then modifying the android:icon attribute under the application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: That is correct for stock android, but not *really* for Amazon devices.